# Parse piped email with PHP

Tags: php, twilio, cpanel

I have been trying to setup up a system with this functionality:

1. Send email to my server
2. Server pipes email to php script
3. Php script parses email getting subject and body
4. Get phone number from subject of email and send text with email body

I have found an email parser here: https://github.com/daniele-occhipinti/php-email-parser

I think I have setup it up correctly but I do not know how to test it besides just sending an email. But I cannot see what my script echos at that point. Also when I do send the email I know something is not working because the text does not send via twilio. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require_once '../resources/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
require('config.php');

// Retrieve Email
require_once("../resources/PlancakeEmailParser.php");

$email = "php://stdin";

$emailParser = new PlancakeEmailParser(file_get_contents($email));

$subject = $emailParser->getSubject();
$text = $emailParser->getPlainBody();



$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $subject);
$phone = "+".$number;
// After this I send the message via Twilio
```

Comment: You should be able to test by dumping a complete email with all headers into it on the command line like `cat emailfile.txt | yourscript.php`. Do so with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see any error output in your terminal

Comment: (or `yourscript.php < emailfile.txt` since cat isn't needed)

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the input so you probably need to buffer the stream to ensure you have received all the data before you try and process it.

Something like this:

```
$dataIn = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
if ($dataIn) {
    $email = '';
    while($line = fgets($dataIn)) { 
        $email .= $line;
    }
    fclose($dataIn);
}
```

Comment: FWIW PHP streams handle the buffering internally, and layering additional buffering on top of it like this tends to cause more problems than it solves. Really you should use the `stream_*` functions to get metadata like whether or not there's more data, or if the stream is closed.

Comment: @Sammitch Is this still the case even when running from the command line? I've found the documentation to be very sparse regarding this. I've never used the stream functions with piped input but I've had problems with no data being received using the OPs method of `file_get_contents` on stdin from the command line. Every example I could find suggested a variation of what I posted above and it's worked for me (in my limited usage), but you probably know a lot more about it than I do.

Comment: For one, we're not talking about *output* buffering which is what differs between CLI and the HTTPd SAPIs. If you're interested in handling the data line by line, or a little at a time for processing, then sure this is the way to go. However, the for the stated purpose of "ensuring you have received all of the data" the additional buffering hinders performance and can break in unexpected ways unless you make use of PHP stream handling functions explicitly. TL;DR: Trust PHP's input buffers, just read from them like normal files.